A way to get element id on click while using it as eventhandler
I programmed a a download progress bar. On click of the element it starts the download and shows the download progress. Sadly I cannot get it to work for multiple buttons and I am at a loss for options.
In detail what i am looking for: on click it gets the calling elements ID and the file supposed to be downloaded when pressing button {num}. Then use the id for the eventhandler and download the file.
First post on here so tell me what i should do differently.
Thanks in advance.


const fileToDownload = 'img/jdk-22_windows-x64_bin.exe';

const startDownloadElem = document.getElementById('startDownload');

  const downloadProgressElem = document.querySelector(
    '.download-progress-bar__progress'
  );

console.log('Initially ' + (window.navigator.onLine ? 'on' : 'off') + 'line');

window.addEventListener('online', () => console.log('Became online'));
window.addEventListener('offline', () => console.log('Became offline'));

//document.getElementById('statusCheck').addEventListener('click', () => console.log('window.navigator.onLine is ' + window.navigator.onLine));


  startDownloadElem.addEventListener('click', () => {
//    downloadProgressElem.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0), rgb(255, 0, 0))';
    console.log('Download Started');
    startDownloadElem.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
    const dataChunks = [];
      fetch(`/${fileToDownload}`)
        .then(response => {
          const reader = response.body.getReader();
          const totalSize = Number(
            response.headers.get('content-length')
          );
          let totalSizeDownloaded = 0;
          downloadProgressElem.classList.remove('error');
          function readData() {
            return reader.read().then(result => {
              if (result.value) {
                dataChunks.push(result.value);
                totalSizeDownloaded += result.value.length;
                const percentage = Math.floor(
                  (totalSizeDownloaded / totalSize) * 100
                );

                console.log(
                  `${totalSizeDownloaded}/${totalSize} (${percentage}%)`
                );
                downloadProgressElem.textContent = `${percentage}%`;
                downloadProgressElem.style.width = `${percentage}%`;
              }

              if (!result.done) {
                return readData();
              }
            });
          }

          return readData();
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Download finished');
          const downloadAnchor = document.createElement('a');
          const blob = new Blob(dataChunks);
          downloadAnchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          downloadAnchor.download = fileToDownload;
          document.body.appendChild(downloadAnchor);
          downloadAnchor.click();
          document.body.removeChild(downloadAnchor);
        })
        .catch( () => {
          downloadProgressElem.textContent = 'Download error';
          downloadProgressElem.classList.add('error');
        })
        .finally(() => {
          startDownloadElem.removeAttribute('disabled');
        })
  })
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#startDownload {
  background: #c50408;
  color: honeydew;
  padding: 10px;
}

#startDownload:disabled {
  background-color: rgb(39, 92, 74);
}

.button-and-progress-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: nowrap column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.download-progress-bar__container {
  margin: 20px 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.download-progress-bar__progress {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0), rgb(255, 0, 0));
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: honeydew;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.download-progress-bar__progress.error {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(138, 0, 226, 0), rgb(138, 0, 226, 1));
}
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <script src="js/app.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="button-and-progress-div">
    <a class="download-start-button" id="startDownload"  data-file-to-download="img/jdk-22_windows-x64_bin.exe">Download</a>

    <div class="download-progress-bar__container" id="progbardiv">
      <div class="download-progress-bar__progress"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>





to use the code i wrote for multiple buttons i would have to make a new .js document with edited id etc, but i want to use one document and use it for multiple buttons.
i have a website with multiple download butttons which each open an individual popup. there i ask if the person wants to continue with downloading the file. if so they click another button (the download progressbar button) and are shown the download progress.
yes i have but i just dont get how to generalize the code...


What does "I cannot get it to work for multiple buttons" mean? Importantly, what do you have in mind it should look like to the user (what's the design, are there supposed to be multiple download progress bars at the same time or what), and have you written anything to attempt to do it?

Is the download popup modal and supposed to stay up until each download is finished? Are you asking anything more than how to get which button element was clicked to start an operation so you can calculate fileToDownload from button attributes rather than defining it in a const declaration?

the popup can be closed, but as long as it is open i want to display the download progress. maybe when closing and reopening the popup too..
and yes, i want the fileToDownload from the buttton instead of the constant so that I can have different files for different buttons.

Here's just a simple example on how you can get it working with onclick attribute...


function downloadMe ( element )
{
  const container = element.parentNode;
  const progress = container.querySelector('.progress-bar');
  const download = element.dataset.download;
  
  // From here on you can manage almost everything you need to do.
  console.log
  ({
      'Container ID:': container.id,
      'Progress Bar:': progress.outerHTML,
      'Download URL:': download,
  });
};
<!-- Fix the HTML below to fit your needs -->
<div id="container-1">
  <a  href="javascript:;"
      onclick="downloadMe(this)"
      data-download="some-url.1.link"
  > Download #1 </a>
  <div class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
<div id="container-2">
  <a  href="javascript:;"
      onclick="downloadMe(this)"
      data-download="some-url.2.link"
  > Download #2 </a>
  <div class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
<div id="container-3">
  <a  href="javascript:;"
      onclick="downloadMe(this)"
      data-download="some-url.3.link"
  > Download #3 </a>
  <div class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>



Note that there's a need to customize the HTML/CSS stuff to fit the needs. This is just a simple example to show a way, from many, to resolve the problem.

thanks a lot, this was exactly what i was trying to do. i tried to make it a function but then i got some error that said 'addEventhandler is not a function'.
If i could ask, do you know how to catch a network error?

@AetherxMana That highly depends on where it is being generated. If it is a rejection from fetch(), then a .catch() should solve it. If it is a thrown error from some function call (like XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send()) you could use try/catch block to wrap the call or attach an error event handler in the XMLHttpRequest instance. See this answer that can help you with that. For other cases, see this other answer that can also help you with that.

Use the click event listener argument
The handler for the download button is passed an event object as its argument when the button is clicked.
The event.target property is a reference to the element the user clicked. For a plain button without images or styled content between the button tags, the target property refers to the button.
For a button that encloses other elements use event.target.closest('button') to get to the actual button element.
